AEC Data Model - Phase Information for Elements
I am using the AEC Data Model Explorer and I am able to retrieve Elements by a Category (Rooms) and return most of the parameter results, but I am unable to get the Phase even when not determining any specific properties.
Here is the code that I am using.
query GetElementsFromCategory {
  elements(
    designId: "WORKING DESIGN ID"
    filter: {query: "property.name.category=='Rooms' and 'property.name.Element Context'==Instance"}
  ) {
    pagination {
      cursor
    }
    results {
      properties{
        results{
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Results are returned similar to below, but there isn't a Phase property.
{
  "data": {
    "elements": {
      "pagination": {
        "cursor": null
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "results": [
              {
                "name": "Comments"
              },
              {
                "name": "Edited by"
              },
              {
                "name": "Workset"
              },
              {
                "name": "External ID"
              },
              {
                "name": "Export to IFC"
              },
              {
                "name": "Export to IFC As"
              },
              {
                "name": "IFC Predefined Type"
              },
              {
                "name": "IfcGUID"
              },
              {
                "name": "Family Name"
              },
              {
                "name": "Element Name"
              },
              {
                "name": "Element Context"
              },
              {
                "name": "Revit Element ID"
              },
              {
                "name": "Area"
              },
              {
                "name": "Computation Height"
              },
              {
                "name": "Department"
              },
              {
                "name": "Base Finish"
              },
              {
                "name": "Ceiling Finish"
              },
              {
                "name": "Floor Finish"
              },
              {
                "name": "Wall Finish"
              },
              {
                "name": "Unbounded Height"
              },
              {
                "name": "Base Offset"
              },
              {
                "name": "Name"
              },
              {
                "name": "Number"
              },
              {
                "name": "Occupancy"
              },
              {
                "name": "Perimeter"
              },
              {
                "name": "Limit Offset"
              },
              {
                "name": "Volume"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Is there a way to get to this information or another reference by call that I can make to get it?
EDIT for results after the answer provided below.
"references": {
            "results": [
              {
                "name": "Upper Limit",
                "displayValue": "LEVEL 1",
                "value": {
                  "id": "this item id"
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "Level",
                "displayValue": "LEVEL 1",
                "value": {
                  "id": "this item id"
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "Phase",
                "displayValue": "New Construction",
                "value": {
                  "id": "this item id"
                }
              }
            ]
          }


I've asked the AEC Data Model team for their feedback on this. Will report back as soon as I have an update.

Phase being a reference property, can be retrieved using 'reference' as seen below:
query GetElementsFromCategory {
  elements(
    designId: "WORKING DESIGN ID"
    filter: {query: "property.name.category=='Rooms' and 'property.name.Element Context'==Instance"}
  ) {
    pagination {
      cursor
    }
    results {
      properties{
        results{
          name
          value
        }
      }
      references{
        results{
          name
          displayValue
          value{
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}


I also wanted to post here for posterity that you can also use the Phases / Phase information in a referencedBy query like this:
query GetElementsFromCategory {
  elements(
    designId: "Your Design ID"
    filter: {query: "property.name.category==Phases and 'property.name.Element Context'==Instance"}
  ) {
    pagination {
      cursor
    }
    results {
      name
      id
      properties(filter: {names:["Element Name","Revit Element ID"]}){
        results{
          name
          value
        }
      }
      referencedBy(name: "Phase", filter:{query:"property.name.category==Rooms"}){
        results{
          name
          id
          properties(filter: {names: ["Area","Name","Number"]}){
            results{
              name
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

